# SDK safe way to hide iPad keyboard when textview is in focus

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview

I have some iPad app where user will navigate using touch screen OR bluetooth keyboard.
I have some hidden textView which is in focus (first responder) and here I detect what is entered from keyboard.

But, when I disconnect keyboard, I have a problem, virtual keyboard appears.

**Can I check if bluetooth keyboard is connected or not, and to set or resign first responder in viewDidLoad or something?**

**or**

I have notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillAppear:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

**Can I hide keyboard on some way when keyboardWillAppear is triggered?**
I tried [textView resignFirstResponder], but without success :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set the inputView to a transparent view:

```
UIView *emptyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
emptyView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textView.inputView = emptyView;
```

In theory that would set the onscreen keyboard to an empty view so it wouldn't be visible. If it doesn't accept a view with no frame then try bumping the width and height to 1. It wouldn't affect the external keyboard; it just wouldn't show up on the device.

Answer (score 5):

You can use performSelector: for that.

```
- (void)hideKeyboard:(UITextView *)textView {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)keyboardWillAppear:(NSNotification *)notification { 
    UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)[self.view viewWithTag:TEXTVIEW_TAG];

    [self performSelector:@selector(hideKeyboard:) withObject:textView];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillAppear:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same. And one correction, it's TextView, not TextField.

Answer (score 0):

You have to schedule the textView's first responder resignation to a dispatch queue, because the process of becoming a first responder probably hasn't been done yet. Easy solution using XCode's dispatch template:

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self.textView resignFirstResponder];
});
```